# Scenekit Xcode 7 positional audio

Tags: audio, scenekit

Has anyone gotten SceneKit positional audio to work in Swift using Xcode 7 and iOS 9?

This is my code to add audio to a node:

```
let spaceAudio = SCNAudioSource(fileNamed: "Arrp1.mp3")  
                spaceAudio.positional = true  
                spaceAudio.loops = true  
                spaceAudio.reverbBlend = 0.5  
                spaceAudio.shouldStream = true  
                let spaceAudioPlayer = SCNAudioPlayer(source: spaceAudio)  
                spaceBall.addAudioPlayer(spaceAudioPlayer)
```

I am getting this error:

[0x1a1950000] AVAudioNodeImpl.h:39: AVAE_CheckNodeHasEngine: required condition is false: _engine != nil
2015-08-20 17:37:19.077 MusiScape[660:53070] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _engine != nil'

Comment: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/15125

Comment: This is actually just a link to the same question I posted on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Yes. Please make sure to always include crosslinks.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I have discoverd that if you first add spaceBall node to the scene graph and then you add the audio player to spaceBall the error will disappear.